# Identity Element of an Elliptic Curve in Cryptography

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

The Group for Elliptic Curve Cryptography doesn't actually seem to have an identity element. You have just randomly defined an element at Infinity as an identity element and said that any other element when added to that element is the same element.

Let us say I have a set & an operator which satisfies all other properties of a group except for the identity element property. Can I convert into a group by creating my own definition of a new element & say it that it is an identity element.

Doesn't this make the whole definition of a Group & the properties it must satisfy meaningless? I could just create my own definitions & create my own imaginary definitions just so it satisfies the property which it otherwise doesn't.

Comment: Were you to try to add a new identity element you would, presumably, have a problem with inverses.  Why would it happen that, given a "group" element $g$ we could always find $h$ such that $gh$ was your newly defined identity?

Comment: If it makes you feel better about elliptic curves, the theory of elliptic functions  let's you identify elliptic curves with embedded tori (at least over $\mathbb C$).  The latter are clearly groups and the identification is a group isomorphism.  Still, it is very useful to have the group structure defined in terms of the underlying plane curve.

Comment: @lulu - i don't understand why I would have a problem with inverses & why whatever problem you say would happen, doesn't happen with the infinity element as defined for elliptic curves?

Comment: @user93353 If $P$ and $Q=-P$ are in your semigroup then so is $P+Q= O$.

Comment: Take the natural numbers. $\{1,2,3, \cdots\}$.  There is no identity but you can create one, we call it $0$.  Now we lack inverses.  Fine, we'll create those as well.  In this way we create the integers.   Good theory!  No worries.  For elliptic curves, it is even better.  Taking the standard form, the thing is symmetric over the $x-axis$ so we can define the inverse of a standard point to be its opposite under refection.  That's a natural involution, and we don't even need to add new points.

Comment: An elliptic curve is by definition a genus $1$ ***projective*** curve with a $K$-point. If the curve is given by a Weierstrass model that point can be chosen to be at infinity. So the construction is really not as ad-hoc as it may seem - it's just that when one has not seen projective curves it looks a little silly. Maybe it is helpful to think of the complex analouge where you have some complex analytic group isomorphism to a torus where it would be very strange to leave out a point and miss out on compactness.

Comment: Also morally one is obliged to think about projective curves if you want intersections to work as expected, because Bezout doesn't work in the affine case.

Comment: It’s really hard to “satisfy all other properties of a group except for the identity element property” because you have to rephrase the inverse element property! There are ways (for example, you could ask that for every $x$ there exist $y$ such that for all $z$, $z(xy)=z$ and $(xy)z=z$; but that just implies the existence of an identity. I guess you could try inverse semigroups (where you only ask that $xyx=x$ and $yxy=y$)...

Comment: If you haven't worked with projective planes before, you might find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates Admittedly, Wikipedia isn't a great place to learn new mathematics. That page isn't too bad though, and has some good links.

Answer (score 2):

We can think of the point at infinity as an extra point created so that the curve works out as a group, but that's unsatisfactory: the point of infinity has no place in the geometric picture and in the algebraic construction we magically add one with no coordinates.

$$E := \{ (x, y) \in k^2 \mid y^2 = x^3 - x + 1 \} \cup \{\mathcal O\}$$

An Elliptic Curve cannot be easily understood without the projective plane.

The **projective plane** is the set $\mathbb{P}^2(k)$ all nonzero triples $(x,y,z)$ in $k^3$ modulo the equivalence relation $(x,y,z) \sim (\lambda x,\lambda  y,\lambda  z)$

With this definition, we can define a **projective point** $(x:y:z)$ is the equivalence class of $(x,y,z)$

Now can we turn these points into Affine point?

Points of the form $(x:y:1)$ are called the **affine points** They form an affine plane ( Euclidean plane) $\mathbb{A}^2(k)$ and that is embedded in the $\mathbb{P}^2(k)$. **This is a natural embedding**. One can define some other embedding too that can change the point at infinity.

What is not mapped into the $\mathbb{A}^2(k)$ is the points of the form $(x:y:0)$ and they are called **point at infinity**.

These point include $(x:y:0)$ and $(1:0:0)$ and they form the **line at infinity** that is a copy of  $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$ embeded in  $\mathbb{P}^2(k)$

The group needs and an identity element and the group law works perfectly with the simple law

$$\texttt{Three points on a line sum to zero, which is the point at infinity.}$$

- In the short Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3 +A x + B$ the point at infinity is $O =(0:1:0)$ Reason; consider it homogeneous equation $E : y^2 z = x^3 + Axz^2 + Bz^3$. This point is the unique point on the line $z=0$ at infinity. ( if $z=0$ then $x=0$ then we get $(0:y:0)$ and scale it with $1/y$. Note that by definition $(0:0:0)$ is not a projective plane.
- Identity element [Edwards curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve)? It is $(0,1)$ They can still embed into Projective Plane. That is very useful in Cryptography. Can you define the identity element as any element up to isomorphism!.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends whether you define the elliptic curve over the affine or projective space.

In the projective plane, the group has the point at infinity, usually written $O=(0:1:0)$, as unit element. All other points of the curve lie in the affine plane given by points of the form $(1:a:b)$, where $a,b$ are elements of the underlying field.

If you define the elliptic curve over the affine space in the first place, there is no point at infinity which amounts to the unit elements.

Then the theory is like that of a semigroup which can always be extended to a monoid by adding a unit element. Just an extension that always works and brings not much more insight.

Comment: Over affine space the operation is only a partial operation, as the sum of two elements may be undefined: e.g., two points with the same $x$-coordinate would have a secant that does not intersect the curve at any third point, and so there is no sum defined.